# Form fields unalignment issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In the code snippet below, all the fields are aligned however that is not the care on my website [here](http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/details/). Can you tell me why is this happening?

P.S. Site is on Wordpress.

```css
#page_2_form input,#page_2_form input[type=text],#page_2_form input[type=email]{
 width: 600px !important;
 padding: .7em .5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="/offer/details/results/" method="POST" id="page_2_form">
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name*"><br>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
 <input style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">
</form>
```

Comment: No. I can't tell you why it's happening, because I don't know what code makes it happen. I only know the code in this post. Anything else will be a uneducated guess. Try "inspect element" to get more relevant code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style

```
 #page_2_form input, #page_2_form input[type=text], #page_2_form input[type=email] {  
    margin: auto 0 10px !important;
 }
```